# background rendering in UWP

Tags: graphics, uwp

I have a canvas control and I am drawing many shapes in the Draw event. As this is in the UI thread, it makes the app laggy, for example, if the redraw is caused by changing the window size, the window size only updates after each redraw which might be 1/2 second.

So I try to do the rendering in a background worker, by creating a RenderTarget:

```
RenderTarget = New CanvasRenderTarget(cc, CSng(cc.ActualWidth), CSng(cc.ActualHeight), cc.Dpi)
drawSesh = RenderTarget.CreateDrawingSession
drawSesh.Clear(Windows.UI.Colors.Transparent)
```

This does draw, but it does not remove the lag, as I cannot run rendering on a non gui thread, so I am using:

```
Await cc.Dispatcher.TryRunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, Sub() bgdraw())
```

.. where cc is my original canvas control, which I presume is putting the task back where I was trying to remove it from.

So how can I create an "independent" gui thread to do my rendering in? Maybe I can do it by creating a separate (hidden) form and doing it there, but that seems clumsy and complex.

Update:
Yes, I can create another form, and get it to do the rendering (and lagging), and trigger drawing updates from my main form. But of course if the second form is minimised, it won't create CanvasControl Draw events. But this is the kind of thing I want.

Or is there a way to draw lines, circles, paths etc. in memory, not in a gui thread at all?

Another update:

Ok, I tried

```
Dim cd = CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice()
RenderTarget = New CanvasRenderTarget(cd, 500, 500, 96)
```

to isolate from the canvas control in use. The drawing works and I can use it is a background worker but it STILL holds up the gui thread and makes the form laggy. So I cannot find any way to draw a complex image without holding up the GUI thread